# Listing all the Facebook photos a user is tagged in using response from FB.api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Right now I'm using the Facebook APIs through JavaScript. So far I can log myself in, and now I'm trying to get information about a user who logs into my website. Here is what I have so far:

```
FB.api('/me/photos', function(response) { console.log(response); } );
```

However, the response only says: "Object {data: Array[0]}", and the Array is empty.

I've also tried using this code:

```
FB.api('/me?fields=photos', function(response) { console.log(response); } );
```

The response I get from the console is: "Object {id: "10152784292783838"}".

How can I get all the photo information? The only ideas I thought of are that I'm not using an access token, but when I tried that it still didn't work. I'm also including 'user_photos' in my scope when I log the user in, but it doesn't change the response. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're using the app's admin/tester/developer users, you should be able to get the data. If not, the array will be empty, because facebook requires an app review for apps which request more than the basic permissions.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#do-you-need-review